# MessageBox is hiding behind main window

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a small app for drawing polygons based on where the user clicked. I built a `PictureBox` for this purpose and implemented its `Paint` event, but now when I show any `MessageBox`es they appear to be rendered behind my main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I committed a great mistake. When I implemented `PictureBox`'s `Paint` event, I put a call to `Refresh()`. `Refresh()` invalidates the status of the main window, which then causes `Refresh()` to be called again and invalidate window again and so on. Because of this event loop, my `MessageBox` was being hidden.

When I removed `Refresh()` call from `Paint` event, everything worked again!